# PHP: Do custom SOAP calls, is SoapClient usefull here?

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, customization

We have to integrate a SOAP webservice into our PHP application (we're using the YII Framework).

We need to send the following example XML requests over this API;

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ver="https://xmlns.customcompany.nl">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <companyName:RequestCompanyNameBreakDownAssistance>
         <companyName:requestInfo>
            <companyName:Product>
               <companyName:BreakDownAssistanceProductType>Basic</companyName:BreakDownAssistanceProductType>
               <companyName:ProductLanguage>NL</companyName:ProductLanguage>
               <companyName:CoveredArea>NLPlusEurope</companyName:CoveredArea>
               <companyName:HasCarReplacementCoverage>false</companyName:HasCarReplacementCoverage>
               <companyName:HasTrailerAndCaravanCoverage>false</companyName:HasTrailerAndCaravanCoverage>
               <companyName:LicensePlate>sfssffssf</companyName:LicensePlate>
               <companyName:Brand>VOLVO</companyName:Brand>
               <companyName:Model>V50</companyName:Model>
               <companyName:ColorId>4</companyName:ColorId>
               <companyName:FuelType>Diesel</companyName:FuelType>
               <companyName:WeightKilogram>1316</companyName:WeightKilogram>
               <companyName:BodyType>Combi</companyName:BodyType>
               <companyName:VehicleInformationType>Car</companyName:VehicleInformationType>
               <companyName:ConstructionYear>2006</companyName:ConstructionYear>
               <companyName:ConstructionMonth>1</companyName:ConstructionMonth>
            </companyName:Product>
            <companyName:Contract>
               <companyName:ProductIdentifier>SFSFSFF</companyName:ProductIdentifier>
               <companyName:StartDate>2015-11-13</companyName:StartDate>
               <companyName:PaymentTerm>Yearly</companyName:PaymentTerm>
               <companyName:FormOfPayment>INC</companyName:FormOfPayment>
               <companyName:OriginalRequestId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</companyName:OriginalRequestId>
               <companyName:ExternalReference/>
               <companyName:PrefillRequestId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</companyName:PrefillRequestId>
               <companyName:IntermediaryCommissionDiscountPercentage>0</companyName:IntermediaryCommissionDiscountPercentage>
               <companyName:IsIndexActive>false</companyName:IsIndexActive>
               <companyName:CreateInvoiceWhenAccepted>false</companyName:CreateInvoiceWhenAccepted>
               <companyName:CommercialProductType>NLPlusEurope</companyName:CommercialProductType>
               <companyName:UnstructuredProductInfo></companyName:UnstructuredProductInfo>
            </companyName:Contract>
            <companyName:AnsweredFinalQuestions>
               <companyName:FinalQuestion>
                  <companyName:QuestionId>MELDING01</companyName:QuestionId>
                  <companyName:Question>Zijn er bijzonderheden?</companyName:Question>
                  <companyName:QuestionDetails>Zijn er bijzonderheden?</companyName:QuestionDetails>
                  <companyName:QuestionAnswer>Yes</companyName:QuestionAnswer>
                  <companyName:QuestionAnswerDetails/>
               </companyName:FinalQuestion>
            </companyName:AnsweredFinalQuestions>
         </companyName:requestInfo>
         <companyName:entityInfo>
            <companyName:Entities>
               <companyName:ContractEntityInfo> 
                  <companyName:CustomerNumber>20151100518456</companyName:CustomerNumber>
                  <companyName:LogicalId>20151100518456</companyName:LogicalId>
                  <companyName:ExternalCustomerNumber/>
                  <companyName:FirstName/>
                  <companyName:Prefix/>
                  <companyName:Initials/>
                  <companyName:Inserts/>
                  <companyName:LastName/>
                  <companyName:Suffix/>
                  <companyName:Nationality>NL</companyName:Nationality>
                  <companyName:PreferredLanguage>NL</companyName:PreferredLanguage>
                  <companyName:Gender>Legal</companyName:Gender>
                  <companyName:Phone>0123456678</companyName:Phone>
                  <companyName:Mobile/>
                  <companyName:Email>john@doe.com</companyName:Email>
                  <companyName:AllowEmailNotifications>true</companyName:AllowEmailNotifications>
                  <companyName:AllowMailings>false</companyName:AllowMailings>
                  <companyName:AllowSmsNotifications>false</companyName:AllowSmsNotifications>
                  <InformPhysically>false</InformPhysically>
                  <companyName:Address>
                     <companyName:Street>Street</companyName:Street>
                     <companyName:HouseNumber>1</companyName:HouseNumber>
                     <companyName:HouseNumberAddition/>
                     <companyName:City>Yew York</companyName:City>
                     <companyName:ZipCode>1234 AZ</companyName:ZipCode>
                     <companyName:CountryCode>NL</companyName:CountryCode>
                     <companyName:IsPostbus>false</companyName:IsPostbus>
                  </companyName:Address>
                  <companyName:ModificationState>Added</companyName:ModificationState>
                  <companyName:HasBusinessDetail>true</companyName:HasBusinessDetail> 
                  <companyName:BusinessDetails>
                     <companyName:CompanyName>Company 1</companyName:CompanyName>
                     <companyName:KVKNumber/>
                     <companyName:CompanyAddress>
                        <companyName:Street>Street</companyName:Street>
                        <companyName:HouseNumber>1</companyName:HouseNumber>
                        <companyName:HouseNumberAddition/>
                        <companyName:City>New Yor</companyName:City>
                        <companyName:ZipCode>1234 AZ</companyName:ZipCode>
                        <companyName:CountryCode>NL</companyName:CountryCode>
                        <companyName:IsPostbus>false</companyName:IsPostbus>
                     </companyName:CompanyAddress>
                  </companyName:BusinessDetails>
                  <companyName:CrmStatus>Customer</companyName:CrmStatus>
                  <companyName:MaritalStatus>Unknown</companyName:MaritalStatus>
                  <companyName:NumberOfAdultsInFamily>0</companyName:NumberOfAdultsInFamily>
                  <companyName:NumberOfChildrenInFamily>0</companyName:NumberOfChildrenInFamily>
                  <companyName:BankAccountIBAN>IBAN</companyName:BankAccountIBAN>
                  <companyName:BankAccountOwner>John Doe</companyName:BankAccountOwner>
               </companyName:ContractEntityInfo>
               <companyName:ContractEntityInfo>
                  <companyName:CustomerNumber/>
                  <companyName:LogicalId>1</companyName:LogicalId>
                  <companyName:ExternalCustomerNumber/>
                  <companyName:FirstName>John</companyName:FirstName>
                  <companyName:Initials>J</companyName:Initials>
                  <companyName:Inserts></companyName:Inserts>
                  <companyName:LastName>Doe</companyName:LastName>
                  <companyName:Gender>Male</companyName:Gender>
               </companyName:ContractEntityInfo>
            </companyName:Entities>
            <companyName:Roles>
               <companyName:ContractRole>
                  <companyName:LogicalId>20151100518456</companyName:LogicalId>
                  <companyName:RoleCode>Ensured</companyName:RoleCode>
                  <companyName:OrderWithinRole>1</companyName:OrderWithinRole>
                  <companyName:ModificationState>Added</companyName:ModificationState>
               </companyName:ContractRole>
               <companyName:ContractRole>
                  <companyName:LogicalId>20151100518456</companyName:LogicalId>
                  <companyName:RoleCode>Owner</companyName:RoleCode>
                  <companyName:OrderWithinRole>1</companyName:OrderWithinRole>
                  <companyName:ModificationState>Added</companyName:ModificationState>
               </companyName:ContractRole>
               <companyName:ContractRole>
                  <companyName:LogicalId>1</companyName:LogicalId>
                  <companyName:RoleCode>Driver</companyName:RoleCode>
                  <companyName:OrderWithinRole>1</companyName:OrderWithinRole>
                  <companyName:ModificationState>Added</companyName:ModificationState>
               </companyName:ContractRole>
            </companyName:Roles>
         </companyName:entityInfo>
         <companyName:options>
            <companyName:Credentials> 
               <companyName:UserId>username</companyName:UserId>
               <companyName:PasswordHash>PasswordHash</companyName:PasswordHash>
               <companyName:Affinity>AFF01</companyName:Affinity>
               <companyName:TargetAffinity>conv01</companyName:TargetAffinity> 
            </companyName:Credentials> 
            <companyName:DisplayLanguage>NL</companyName:DisplayLanguage>
            <companyName:RequestType>Request</companyName:RequestType>
         </companyName:options>
      </companyName:RequestCompanyNameBreakDownAssistance>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

As you can see, there are custom namespaces used, and also custom array's.

When i try to send this with the default SoapClient from PHP, i get the following XML request output;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="https://xmlns.customcompany.nl">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:RequestCompanyNameBreakDownAssistance/>
    <param1><item>
      <key>Entities</key>
      <value>
      <item>
      <key>ContractEntityInfo</key>
      <value>
      <item>
      <key>CustomerNumber</key>
      <value/>
      </item><item>
      <key>LogicalId</key>
      <value>1</value>
      </item><item>
      <key>ExternalCustomerNumber</key>
      <value/>
      </item><item>
      <key>FirstName</key>
      <value>John</value>
      </item><item>
      <key></key>
      <value>J</value>
      </item><item>
      <key>Inserts</key>
      <value/>
      </item><item>
      <key>LastName</key>
      <value>Doe</value>
      </item><item>
      <key>Gender</key>
      <value>Male</value>
      </item>
      </value>
      </item><item>
      <key>Roles</key>
      <value><item>
        <key>0</key>
        <value><item>
          <key>LogicalId</key>
          <value>20151100994790</value>
          </item><item>
          <key>RoleCode</key>
          <value>Ensured</value>
          </item><item>
          <key>OrderWithinRole</key>
          <value>1</value>
          </item><item>
          <key>ModificationState</key>
          <value>Added</value>
          </item></value>
        </item><item>
        <key>1</key>
        <value><item>
          <key>LogicalId</key>
          <value>20151100994790</value>
          </item><item>
          <key>RoleCode</key>
          <value>Owner</value>
          </item><item>
          <key>OrderWithinRole</key>
          <value>1</value>
          </item><item>
          <key>ModificationState</key>
          <value>Added</value>
          </item></value>
        </item><item>
        <key>3</key>
        <value><item>
          <key>LogicalId</key>
          <value>1</value>
          </item><item>
          <key>RoleCode</key>
          <value>Driver</value>
          </item><item>
          <key>OrderWithinRole</key>
          <value>1</value>
          </item><item>
          <key>ModificationState</key>
          <value>Added</value>
          </item></value>
        </item></value>
      </item>
      </value>
      </item></param1>
    <param2><item>
      <key>Credentials</key>
      <value><item>
        <key>UserId</key>
        <value>UserName</value>
        </item><item>
        <key>PasswordHash</key>
        <value>PasswordHash</value>
        </item><item>
        <key>Affinity</key>
        <value>AFF01</value>
        </item><item>
        <key>TargetAffinity</key>
        <value>AFF02</value>
        </item><item>
        <key>DisplayLanguage</key>
        <value>NL</value>
        </item></value>
      </item></param2>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

How can I send requests based on the structure that is needed for this webservice (code example 1)? Do i need a custom SoapClient to do this? Or can i use the shipped SoapClient of PHP with different options, namespaces and array structures?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you [nuSoap SOAP Client](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/). Use it into Yii Framework (tested on Yii 1.1.15) copying `nusoap` folder into protected/vendors and then in your code you can explore with your custom requirements. Here a little sample:

```
Yii::import('application.vendors.nusoap.*');
require_once "lib/nusoap.php";            
$client = new nusoap_client('YOUR_SOAP_URL_WITHOUT_WSDL_SUFFIX');
$result = $client->call('method_name', array('parameter_name' => $parameterValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would strongly advise you to do is to use a WSDL to PHP generator so you'll build the XML without wondering how to do it as each parameter will be defined using its PHP "mirror" class. And if you have multiple times the same type of parameter within an element (several companyName for example) then you'll only have to create an array of mutiple companyName PHP object then pass this array to the parent object.

To do so, you can use [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) that should work and ease you your work.

Personnally I used nuSOAP or SoapClient but it was never really helping for understanding how to build the request!